# How to remove a git remote branch

Tags: git, github

So i've got something like this for a repository atm.

```
D-Hewards-MacBook-Pro:project dheward$ git branch -r
origin/master
unfuddle/master
```

Interestingly because it is the master branch of the unfuddle repo it will not let me delete it using command such as:-

```
git push unfuddle :master
```

One points to unfuddle and the other to another git repo. What I want to do is remove the unfuddle one from this repo and stop tracking it altogether.

Does anyone know what I can do to achieve this? Tried a few things to little avail.

SOLVED:

```
D-Hewards-MacBook-Pro:projectname dheward$ git branch -r -d unfuddle/master
Deleted remote branch unfuddle/master (was bb55c89).
D-Hewards-MacBook-Pro:projectname dheward$ git remote rm unfuddle
D-Hewards-MacBook-Pro:projectname dheward$ git branch -r origin/master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you just want to remove the remote-tracking branch from your repository, you could do

```
git branch -r -d unfuddle/master
```

You can also remove your pointer to the `unfuddle` repository altogether:

```
git remote rm unfuddle
```

If you actually want to remove the `master` branch from the repository that `unfuddle` points to (like your `push` command seems to attempt), you can only do that if `master` is not checked out there or if `receive.denyDeleteCurrent` is `false` there.

Comment: Yeah which it would seem that it's not. Since it's currently rejecting it and of course I have no control over the receive.denyDeleteCurrent setting. Gonna try out your solution now though :D